# Where do you configure spark and hive settings on local install of jupyter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to configure Spark on my local IDE and local install of Conda jupyter environment to use our corp spark/hive connect which looks something specs similar to this:

host: mycompany.com 
port: 10003

I tried to configure spark-default.conf

```
spark.master  spark://mycompany.com:10003
```

And when I try and call the spark context : sc
I get the following error with Jupyter:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

Does anyone know of any good documentation that I can use to configure my local instance of jupyter and or Netbeans to use Spark with Scala or Python?

Comment: You'll find a good tutorial here https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0 to configure jupyter for pyspark

Comment: Thanks @Marie I'm able to set up Spark locally based on the link you provided. However, I don't know how to point to our corp. cluster